# rc.local не работает автозагрузка

Tags: linux, debian, автозагрузка

Стоит `Debian 7`. В /etc/rc.local записал данные

```
screen -d -m -S jabber sh /var/www/jabber/jabber.sh
```

Содержимое `jabber.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd  /var/www/jabber/
mono JabberMatrixConsole.exe
```

Если я вручную напишу `screen -d -m -S jabber sh /var/www/jabber/jabber.sh`
оно работает, однако автозагрузка не хочет работать. Как быть?

Comment: У вас или rc.local не стартует (проверьте, в /etc/rc2.d должна быть ссылка вида Snnrc.local, где `nn` какая либо цифра, указывающая на /etc/rc.local). Если ее нет, то ее надо создать. Цифру побольше лучше поставить. Или могут быть проблемы с путями. Попробуйте указать полные пути к screen и особенно к mono

Comment: 1. как вы определили, что «не работает»? 2. от имени какого пользователя вы выполняете команду «Если я вручную напишу…»? 3. `/etc/rc.local` вообще интерпретируется у вас при загрузке?